# Bash: Convert file from hex character encoding to utf8

Tags: node.js, bash, encoding, utf-8, hex

I have a file content I need to decode.

The original data was in a `utf8` format and was encrypted and as part of this process stored in a file in `hex` format, 2 hex characters per unicode character (base 16 number byte).

node.js code similar to the following was used to generate this data:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const algorithm = 'AES-256-CBC';

const encrypt = async (value, password, iv) {
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, password, iv);
    let encrypted = cipher.update(value, 'utf8', 'hex')
    encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
    return encrypted;
}
```

I would like some `linux` bash script (not node.js code) which would essentially convert the source file into a `utf8` encoded file.

Is there a simple was of doing this?

I have been looking at tools like `iconv` but struggling to find answers.

Once the file content it decoded I can then use openssl to decrypt.

Comment: Please provide an example of the data you are trying to convert. Also, after conversion you won’t have a `utf8` string, you’ll have a binary blob which `openssl` will decrypt into a `utf8` string.  `openssl` is able to read base64-encoded data directly, but unfortunately not hex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what is referred to be "source file". If you mean the hex encoded encrypted data that can not be converted into UTF-8.

Encrypted data is 8-bit binary that appears to be random bits/bytes. Arbitrary binary data is not representable in UTF-8, not all binary values are legal UTF-8 characters.

Instead what you need to do is convert the hex into binary and pass that binary to the decryption method.